# python: using threading , apply thread timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, python-multithreading

I'm using threading library in a  multithreading script. I want to implement a timeout on the thread. Thus, if the thread hasn't returned `task_done` after a specified amount of time, it should come out of the function and return `task_done`

Here is my code:

```
def create_workers():
    for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()


def create_jobs():
    for d in Date_set :
        queue.put(d)
    queue.join()
    scrape()


def scrape_page(thread_name, page_url):
    print(thread_name + ' now working on ' + page_url)
    get_active_urls_perDay(session=s,Date=page_url,County=Cty, courtSystem=CS, PT=P)


def work():
    while True:
        url = queue.get()
        scrape_page(threading.current_thread().name, url)
        Date_set.remove(url)
        print str(len(Date_set)) + " days more to go!"
        print "Number of threads active", threading.activeCount()
        queue.task_done()


def scrape():
    queued_links = Date_set
    if len(queued_links) > 0:
        print(str(len(queued_links)) + ' days in the queue')
        create_jobs()
```

In the `work` function, I want to implement a timeout on the thread.
Otherwise the code runs fine, but the threads which haven't returned `task_done` halt the code and it keeps waiting for them to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import threading
import Queue
import time

lock = threading.Lock()

Date_set = ['127.0.0.1/test1', '127.0.0.1/test3', '127.0.0.1/test3', '127.0.0.1/test4']
queue = Queue.Queue()
NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 3


def create_jobs():
    for d in Date_set:
        queue.put(d)
    # scrape()

thread_list = []

def create_workers():
    for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work)
        thread_list.append(t)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()


def join_all():
    [t.join(5) for t in thread_list]


def scrape_page(thread_name, page_url):
    time.sleep(1)
    lock.acquire()
    print(thread_name + ' now working on ' + page_url)
    print page_url + ' done'
    lock.release()
    # get_active_urls_perDay(session=s,Date=page_url,County=Cty, courtSystem=CS, PT=P)


def work():
    while True:
        if queue.empty() is True:
            break
        url = queue.get()
        try:
            scrape_page(threading.current_thread().name, url)
            # Date_set.remove(url)
            lock.acquire()
            print str(len(Date_set)) + " days more to go!"
            print "Number of threads active", threading.activeCount()
            lock.release()
        finally:
            queue.task_done()


def scrape():
    queued_links = Date_set
    if len(queued_links) > 0:
        print(str(len(queued_links)) + ' days in the queue')
        create_jobs()


# s=session
# Cty= County
# CS= courtSystem
# P= PT
# Date_set = create_dates_set(start_filingDate, end_filingDate)
create_jobs()
create_workers()
join_all()
print 'main thread quit and all worker thread quit even if it is not finished'
# scrape()
# return case_urls
```

this example would work, I use sleep(200) to simulate the `get_active_urls_perDay`, and after 15s, the script will stop. if you replace sleep(200) to sleep(1) all threads will be finished and main thread exit.

Comment: It is working but it caused all the threads and main process to end as soon as 1 thread got stuck, the whole code ended successfully...

Comment: Oh! No no... Your code is working fine it stopped just one thread... but the whole code exited once too. Can we just stop that whole code end somehow?

Comment: what do you mean `stopped just one thread`?  when the all join reached the timeout the whole code will be  end.

Comment: I think when one thread broke the code came out of threading to print the statement you wrote there and then ended but other threads kept working in background. for example. There are 8 threads working. When thread number 1 failed, the code terminated by printing `main thread quit and all worker thread quit even if it is not finished` while remaining 7 threads were still working.

Comment: No, main thread will not exit if only one thread broke the code, it will exit until all threads whose `join()` method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout occurs.  when main thread exit, all working threads also killed(working threads are hang more than 5 seconds(join timeout) and kill them).

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_jobs():
    for d in Date_set :
        queue.put(d)
    scrape()

def create_workers():
    thread_list=[]
    for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work)
        thread_list.append(t)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    return thread_list

def join_all(thread_list):
    [t.join(5) for t in thread_list]



def scrape_page(thread_name, page_url):
    print(thread_name + ' now working on ' + page_url)
    get_active_urls_perDay(session=s,Date=page_url,County=Cty, courtSystem=CS, PT=P)


def work():
    while True:
        url = queue.get()
        try:
            scrape_page(threading.current_thread().name, url)
            Date_set.remove(url)
            print str(len(Date_set)) + " days more to go!"
            print "Number of threads active", threading.activeCount()
        finally:
            queue.task_done()

def scrape():
    queued_links = Date_set
    if len(queued_links) > 0:
        print(str(len(queued_links)) + ' days in the queue')
        create_jobs()


s=session
Cty= County
CS= courtSystem
P= PT
Date_set = create_dates_set(start_filingDate, end_filingDate)
t_list= create_workers()
join_all(t_list)
scrape()
return case_urls
```